# can't start test network using zombienet-macos

Tags: substrate-parachain-template, relay-chain, zombienet

I am using `polkadot` from [polkadot-sdk](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk) github repo and from [this article](https://docs.substrate.io/test/simulate-parachains/#prepare-a-working-folder-with-the-binaries) to Simulate parachains in a test network, it says to checkout latest release of polkadot which might be `git checkout release-v1.0.0` but I can't do that from `polkadot-sdk`,

```
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air polkadot-sdk % git checkout release-v1.0.0
error: pathspec 'release-v1.0.0' did not match any file(s) known to git
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air polkadot-sdk % cd polkadot 
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air polkadot % git checkout release-v1.0.0
error: pathspec 'release-v1.0.0' did not match any file(s) known to git
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air polkadot %
```

also using latest `zombienet-macos v1.3.66`

[image]

and I think because of not using `latest release of polkadot` I am getting this error,

```
Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:53031/metrics

Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:53027/metrics

     Error:  
         Timeout(300), "getting desired metric value 1 within 300 secs".


     Error:  
         Timeout(300), "getting desired metric value 1 within 300 secs".


     Error:  
         Timeout(300), "getting desired metric value 1 within 300 secs".


     Error:  
         Timeout(300), "getting desired metric value 1 within 300 secs".

Error:       Error: At least one of the nodes fails to start

undefined
┌────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Node'              │ /var/folders/q3/d699hkpx49xfy236ph7sltr40000gn/T/zombie-373ef077d6dbe13b0887f26f9ec9fa2f_-18674-P… │
│ s logs:            │                                                                                                    │
│ m                  │                                                                                                    │
└────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air xcav %
```

Someone please tell me how to figure our this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the docs has to be updated with the new repository.

In the new repo go to the [polkadot folder](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/master/polkadot) and follow the instructions there to generate the polkadot binary.