# What version of polkadot relaychain and substrate-parachain-template can be used?

Tags: parachain, relay-chain

I am following this tutorial:

https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/prepare-a-local-relay-chain/

While downloading the source code for relaychain I encountered the error:

"fatal: Remote branch release-v1.0.0 not found in upstream origin"

When I checked at:
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/releases

It has a new release that is "Polkadot v1.1.0" and it says that the three repositories Substratte, Polkadot and Cumulus are not merged.

I am really confused, since I wanted to connect substrate parachain with the polladot relaychian. So, what version of polkadot relaychain and susbtrate-parachain-tempalte I should use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in that tutorial, I have seen it before in this previous StackExchange question: [can't start test network using zombienet-macos](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9839/cant-start-test-network-using-zombienet-macos).

I have open an issue in the Docs repository: [Fix wrong branch of new repository](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/pull/2064) so hopefully it will be fixed soon.

But for now I suggest you don't do the `git checkout release-v1.0.0` because the branch doesn't exist and just build the binaries (`cargo build --release`) on the Master branch, so you can follow the rest of the tutorial propertly.

Comment: Thank you @alex for the help. 

BTW, I observed alot of errors in tutorial. In most cases, the tutorials are out of sync with the development activity/github repo

Comment: If you have time you can submit an issue for the documentation team to look into: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/issues/new/choose

Comment: Sure, thank you.